# Axiom of Determinacy for higher cardinalities?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, axioms

I feel kind of stupid asking this question, but upon browsing AD and variations of AC I can not help but wonder if there is also work for AD with higher cardinalities, like $\alpha^\alpha$-games for aribtrary cardinal $\alpha$. For AC we could define variations AC$(a,b)$ with $a,b\in\{\alpha,<\!\alpha,\infty:\alpha\textit{ some cardinal}\}$, where for instance AC$(\omega,\infty)$ is *countable choice* or AC$(\infty,<\!\omega)$ is *choice for finite sets*.

Now the *axiom of determinateness* is orginally defined for $2^\omega$ games (1) but is as *axiom of determinacy* nowadays more widely spread for $\omega^\omega$ games. I'm wondering if there is work on determinacy for $\alpha^\alpha$ games and arbitrary cardinalities.

From what I understand AC$(\aleph_1,\infty)$ already contradicts AD$(\omega^\omega)$ and AD$(\omega^\omega)$ implies AC$(\omega,\aleph_1)$. I reckon we can not have an axiom of determinacy for all cardinalities at the same time, since AD$(\aleph_1^{\aleph_1})$ assumedly contradicts AD$(\aleph_0^{\aleph_0})$.

Or am I missing something, is AD$(\alpha^\alpha)$ provably contradicting for any $\alpha>\omega$?

(1) *Mycielski, Jan; Steinhaus, Hugo*, A mathematical axiom contradicting the axiom of choice, Bulletin de l'Académie Polonaise des Sciences. Série des Sciences Mathématiques, Astronomiques et Physiques.. 10, 1-3 (1962). [ZBL0106.00804](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0106.00804).

Comment: Note though that $\mathop{AD}(\omega_1^{\omega_1})$ implies $\mathop{AD}$, so the argument really shows that these axioms are inconsistent with ZF.
Also, AD for $\omega^\omega$ and $2^\omega$ are the same. One inclusion is obvious, in the other direction you can easily transform the game (for example, they code their numbers by playing as many $1$'s and while one player is playing $1$'s the other has to play $0$'s until the one player plays a $0$, when it's the other player's turn toplay $1$'s)

Comment: Can you elaborate on that, especially on the inconsistency part? Ok, I get the $\omega^\omega$ and $2^\omega$ now.

But so AD$(\omega_1^{\omega_1})$ implies and contradicts AD?

Comment: Yes, obviously you can artificially lengthen every game of countable length to have length $\omega_1$ and then the winning strategy there gives you one for the game of countable length. So, if $\textsf{AD}(\omega_1,\omega_1)$(I find the other notation not too clear), then $\textsf{AD}$ holds. On the other hand though, it implies its negation. The only possibility left is that $\textsf{AD}(\omega_1,\omega_1)$ is inconsistent with $\textsf{ZF}$. (In fact, already games of length $\omega_1$ with moves from $\{0,1\}$ are undetermined, as you can see in Noah's answer (or the link in his answer)).

Comment: Has my answer addressed your question fully?

Comment: Hmm, your question is difficult to me. I guess one could say your answer covers all that I asked for. On the other hand, I find above two comments by @martin.koeberl much more helpful for my actual question.

Comment: If your question is fully answered, I think you should accept the existing answer. Unless, there is a chance of the comments being deleted at some point (is that only a theoretical possibility or does this happen), in which case I'm happy to expand my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 8):

See [this answer to a question of mine from a while ago](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/100196/indeterminacy-of-long-games). Basically:

- length-$\omega_1$ games on $\{0, 1\}$ are not determined,

and

- length-$\omega$ games on $\omega_1$ are not determined,

each provably in ZF. So all that's left, really, is games of length $\alpha$ for $\alpha$ countable, on a countable set $X$.

Well, $X$ might as well now be $\omega$, so really we're talking about countable-length games on the natural numbers. And these rapidly yield strong determinacy principles! For instance, it's a good exercise to show that length-$\omega^2$ determinacy on $\omega$ implies $AD_\mathbb{R}$. Neeman has studied the determinacy of long games, and Martin and Woodin independently showed that ZF + AD + "all sets of reals have [scales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_(descriptive_set_theory))" implies the following principle:

$$(*)\quad\mbox{For each $\alpha<\omega_1$, every length-$\alpha$ game on $\omega$ is determined.}$$

(See [the beginning of this paper of Neeman](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~ineeman/int.pdf).) And you may find Neeman's book [The Determinacy of Long Games](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~ineeman/long-games.htm) an interesting source in general.

---

An interesting side question is how strong the Martin-Woodin hypothesis is, in terms of consistency strength. As an upper bound, it is consistent relative to at most the existence of simultaneous limit of strongs and limit of Woodins that determinacy holds and every set of reals is universally Baire and hence is determined and has a scale (this is a result of [Larson, Sargsyan, and Wilson](https://www.math.uci.edu/~twilson/papers/every-set-uB.pdf)); I suspect less is needed, but an obstacle to this is the fact that scales provably fail to exist in $L(\mathbb{R})$ at the $\Pi^2_1$ level.

Comment: It's towards the bottom on the first page of his introductory article on the determinacy of long games (which can be found at math.ucla.edu/~ineeman/int.pdf). It seems to be a result of Woodin and Martin (independently), that from $\mathsf{AD}$
and all sets of reals admitting scales, one gets determinacy for all countable-length-games on $\omega$.

Comment: @martin.koeberl Thanks! I've incorporated that into my answer. Incidentally, do you know if the consistency bound of the Martin/Woodin hypothesis which I've stated is (even remotely close to) optimal?

Comment: I actually think the bound you give is close to optimal.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Oh neat! Is there a snappy reason why?

Comment: I have read somewhere that AD implies that there is no cardinal strictly between $\omega$ and $\lvert 2^\omega\rvert$. Is this included in above statement of $\alpha, X$ being countable as only options left?

Is there an intuitive reason for this as well? I mean, it does not yet imply CH, correct?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Since determinacy is formulated in a choiceless context, it seems to me there's still room to formulate determinacy for games on certain uncountable sets which are not well-orderable, which might circumvent your dichotomy here (although granted, the question only asked about determinacy for games on cardinals).